# If else in Mysql join

Tags: mysql, join

I want to fetch questions from table but I have a problem that, I have username stored as foreign key and now I want to join to the table whether its customers or employees i.e. I want to fetch the name of user and I will have to join to customer table if the question is asked by customer or employee table if it is asked by an employee

```
table question
id question askedby
1  Hello     user
2  What is?  user


table login
id username password role
1  john       pp123  emp
2  haris      xx589  cus

table customer
id fname  lname username
1  Johnny  Kip    John

table employee
id fname  lname username backgroud dutytime
1  Harisi  Ahmed  Haris    xyz       19:00
```

I want to do all this in one query and I could only join question to login table and now I have to see if role is "emp" then join with customer otherwise join with employee.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can me very many solutions for such task. Here are three more.

I must admit, that I'm not sure about performance of each. You have to test that for yourself :)

```
SELECT
     a.*
    ,IF(c.id IS NULL, e.fname, c.fname) AS fname
    ,IF(c.id IS NULL, e.lname, c.lname) AS lname
FROM
    login a
    LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.username=a.username AND a.role='cus'
    LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.username=a.username AND a.role='emp'
;
```

or

```
SELECT
     a.*
    ,COALESCE(
        (SELECT c.fname FROM customer c WHERE c.username=a.username AND a.role='emp'),
        (SELECT e.fname FROM employee e WHERE e.username=a.username AND a.role='cus')
    ) AS fname
    ,COALESCE(
        (SELECT c.lname FROM customer c WHERE c.username=a.username AND a.role='emp'),
        (SELECT e.lname FROM employee e WHERE e.username=a.username AND a.role='cus')
    ) AS lname
FROM
    login a
;
```

or probably better

```
SELECT
     a.*
    ,IF(a.role='cus',
        (SELECT c.fname FROM customer c WHERE c.username=a.username),
        (SELECT e.fname FROM employee e WHERE e.username=a.username)
    ) AS fname
    ,IF(a.role='cus',
        (SELECT c.lname FROM customer c WHERE c.username=a.username),
        (SELECT e.lname FROM employee e WHERE e.username=a.username)
    ) AS lname
FROM
    login a
;
```

I personally think (not tested), that first of my SELECTs should be better that others, but MySQL sometimes likes (better performance) sub-selects much better than joins.

Comment: Thanks man, last statement works like a charm, I didn't use first one because I have to use few more joins as well

Comment: BTW, I guess you know that you can "ask" MySQL to show it's execution plan for each of these. This can be done with `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

One convoluted way of doing this is using UNION ALL like

```
select *
from login a
join (
  select 'cus' role, username
  from customer
  union all
  select 'emp' role, username
  from employee) b on a.role = b.role and a.username = b.username;
```

Definitely not efficient :D

Comment: UNION ALL can create huge temporary table and as you said - more likely that'll not be efficient especially for big tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that usernames are unique across Customers and Employees then you can do the following (If they aren't you will get duplicate rows which you can remove with the DISTINCT keyword but that's a bit poor):

```
Select *
From Question q
Left join Customer c on c.username = q.askedby
Left join employee e on e.username = q.askedby
```

Comment: this returns all columns of both customer and employee.. above solution with if condition is true